Movie about a goverment made robot or clone who kills some guys, then runs away from his creators
I don't remember much about this movie other than the beginning.
It starts off showing a couple who lives in this run down house, and they basically just smoke weed and lounge around all the time. They lay on top of their car and watch the stars sometimes too and I think they are fighting when the movie starts.
A little bit later, the guy goes to the gas station or a small market, and some guys are robbing the place. He kills the robbers and starts freaking out saying he didn't mean to and he doesn't know what happened. Then, it comes out that he's like a government made robot or clone type thing, and the girl living with him was employed to protect him or monitor him. The rest of the movie, I think, is him and his girl running from whoever created him.

You're describing American Ultra

Small-town stoner Mike Howell spends most of his time getting high and writing a graphic novel about a superhero monkey. What Mike doesn't know is that he was trained by the CIA to be a lethal killing machine. When the agency targets him for termination, his former handler activates his latent skills, turning the mild-mannered slacker into a deadly weapon. Now, the utterly surprised Mike must use his newfound abilities to save himself and his girlfriend from getting wasted by the failed test subjects that are sent after him by the CIA.





YES THANK YOU SO MUCH

Glad I could help. You can mark the question as answered by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.
